mostrar un campo de otra tabla en un formulario
Tengo dos tablas: clientes y facturas.
En la segunda el campo cliente es un id que es clave ajena de la primera.
Si pudiera, me gustaría hacer dos cosas:
que en la tabla donde listo todas las facturas me apareciera el nombre del cliente y no su id y otra, que en el form donde introduzco las facturas, pudiera escribir bien el id o bien el nombre del cliente.
He escrito esto:
function find_all_receipt(){
        global $db;
        $sql="SELECT r.id,r.date,c.nombre,r.total,r.file";
        $sql.=" FROM receipts r";
        $sql.=" INNER JOIN clients c";
        $sql.=" ON r.client=c.id";
        $sql.=" ORDER BY r.id DESC";
        return find_by_sql($sql);
    }

Prero me dice:

Warning: Undefined array key "client" in
C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\receipts.php on line 41
La línea 41 es esta:

<td class="text-center"><?php echo remove_junk($receipt['client']); ?></td>


Nada de perdón men, eres usuario viejo sabes como funciona SOes. Pon lo que has intentado o errores que te da y listo... PD: ya buscaste sobre JOIN querys??

He añadido en la pregunta la unión de las tablas

Dónde define remove_junk($receipt['client']); ?

en la página donde está la tabla que muestra todas las facturas

Entonces si tenias cosas para mostrar (¬_¬) Perdona @CharlyUtrilla pero de verdad parece que no te gusta investigar nada por tu cuenta men y todo lo quieres de una, el error es clarísimo y si hubieras hecho una búsqueda rápida del error en Google ahora ya sabrías la respuesta. Busca Warning: Undefined array key in using PHP en Google y luego nos actualizas. No es que no te quiera ayudar, pero el error es super básico y hasta donde veo ya tienes algo de experiencia programando. El ser autodidacta también es una regla para los informáticos, máxime los programadores... Yo te ayudare luego.

He puesto esto y me salta al else:                                                               <?php if(isset($receipt['client'])){ ?>       <td class="text-center"><?php echo remove_junk($receipt['client']); ?></td>       <?php }else{ ?>       <td class="text-center"><?php echo "NO EXISTE"; ?></td>       <?php } ?> Así que entiendo que la consulta está mal hecha.

Ya lo he podido arreglar. Había que poner AS client después de c.nombre.

Ojala tu próxima pregunta no sea como tus ultimas, esperamos verte más esforzado la próxima vez :-) Dale, todos aprendemos así men, TODOS...

function find_all_receipt(){
        global $db;
        $sql="SELECT r.id,r.date,c.nombre AS client,r.total,r.file";
        $sql.=" FROM receipts r";
        $sql.=" INNER JOIN clients c";
        $sql.=" ON r.client=c.id";
        $sql.=" ORDER BY r.id DESC";
        return find_by_sql($sql);
    }

Si no le indicas el nombre del campo en el que va a ir, no lo reconoce, aunque esté bien insertado en el array.

basciamente, no hay ningun campo con el nombre que buscabas...

Es que el error era más que lógico: Undefined array key "client" hasta alguien que diga no saber nada de inglés se daría cuenta que "la llave cliente del array no está definida" (spanglich). Vez que es cierto lo que te dije?? Antes de preguntar por cualquier error que te de (en cualquier aspecto de la vida) busca sobre eso, te aseguro que a otros ya les ha salido y lo han resuelto, porque solo nos haces pensar que todo te gusta en la boca (como dicen por ahí) y tampoco podemos ganarte el sueldo, comprendes?? Me alegra que fueras capaz de resolverlo por ti mismo men :-) sigue así...
